# how to show a window only one time?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want display a window only one time. When the user click on this button:

```
private void Notification_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NotificationSettings notifications = new NotificationSettings();
        notifications.ShowDialog();
    }
```

this will create a new window, I want that if there is already a window opened the user can't open a new one. There is an option in xaml for tell to compiler this? I remember the vb.net with windows form that allow to set the option to show only one windows at time.

Thanks.

Comment: If you use `ShowDialog` (modal), there shouldn't be much the user can do anyway, no?

Comment: ShowDialog also block the input of parent window

Comment: Well, but given that you had that in your code the assumption would be that you actually want that.

Answer (score 0):

Just hold a reference to your window in a field/property and check if it's `Visisble` already.

Comment: I though this, but I really need to add code and if control to a simple thing like this?

Comment: why microsoft does not provide a simple thing like this?

Comment: Because it can be modeled easily with two lines of code, there is no need to provide such functionality.

Comment: a simple option "prevent other instance" seems better to me

Comment: @Harold Finch ShowDialog already does what you want.  You can't click the button on the first form so long as the form you opened with the ShowDialog() is still open.  I don't really see what the actual issue is here.

Answer (score 0):

well I am not sure what is NotificationSettings exactly but for a window you can create a bool flag to mark when the window is opened and closed, check this code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    bool WindowFlag = false;

    private void button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window TestWindows = new Window();
        TestWindows.Closing += TestWindows_Closing;

        if (WindowFlag == true)
        {               
            MessageBox.Show("The Window is already opened");
        }
        else
        {
            TestWindows.Show();
            WindowFlag = true;
        }
    }

    private void TestWindows_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        WindowFlag = false;
    }
}
```